# button perform click not working

Tags: android

This is my code to perform click automatically when the activity opens but it is not working

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notify);
        editspeak = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editspeak);
       btspeak=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);


      // speakout();
      //  mydb = new DBhandler(this);
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
        String name=preferences.getString("NAME",null);
        editspeak.setText(name);

        t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
            }
        });

        btspeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = editspeak.getText().toString();
        t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
               // bt.setPressed(false);
               // bt.invalidate();

            }
        });
       btspeak.performClick();
```

Comment: any error ?????

Comment: nope its not showing any error

Comment: what is performClick(); ?

Comment: share all code..

Comment: @omi its to automatically perform button click when the activity opens

Comment: @omi that is the full code am having on that activity

Comment: if any of you have code to perform text to speach automatically please share

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you call `speak` before the `TextToSpeech` is fully initialised (you can add a few logs to check this). To fix this behaviour you can use `performClick` in this way to delay the call until everything else is finished initialising:

```
    btspeak.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btspeak.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: is `btnspeak.post()` going to make any delay?

Comment: Yes, a small delay will occur enough to allow all components to finish the initialisation process. Also, if you want to delay it for a fixed amount of time you can use the `postDelayed` method and specify the time in milliseconds.

Comment: Actually, it may work. But the logic is not adding delay. Did you heard about message queue?

Comment: This is exactly what  `post` does. It adds the `Runnable` to a queue that will be executed later.